# NsdManager never discover any services on Google Pixel 3 (Pie)

Tags: android, kotlin, nsd, google-pixel, nsdmanager

Same code works on Samsung S8 and Sony XZ, but not on Google Pixel 3.

I start the discovery with NsdManager with:

```
nsdManager.discoverServices("_test_service._tcp.", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, discoveryListener)
```

The discoveryListener gives onDiscoveryStarted callback with same serviceType as specified. I sit on same wifi as my service, I wait and wait but no onServiceFound callback comes. The onServiceFound callback comes milliseoncds after starting discovery on Samsung S8 and Sony XZ.

Are there any known issues regarding the NsdManager for Google Pixel 3?

Comment: Have you tried with pure TCP, without "test_service"?

Comment: Yep but I don't find any services on the network

Comment: I was looking for printers inside the same WiFi network and it worked okay. Are you sure that devices you are looking for are in the same network?

Comment: Yep. I've tried several times with different devices other than the ones mentioned. Sony phones works but the NsdManager gives up after a while of starting/stopping discoveries. But the Google Pixel 3 still never finds any devices. Are there certain routers that the Pixel 3 doesn't support?

Comment: Tried with jmDNS but did not work on the Google Pixel 3 either.

Comment: See workaround to the Pixel behavior here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53630778/78356